# C# call interface method with default implementation

Tags: c#

I have the following interface and class:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void A();
   
    void B() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("B"); 
    } 
}

class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

I'd like to instantiate MyClass and call B() like so:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
x.B();
```

However, this doesn't work since MyClass does not contain a definition for 'B'.  Is there anything I can add to MyClass so this code calls the default implementation of B() in IMyInterface?

I understand the code below works, but I don't want to change the data type from MyClass to IMyInterface.

```
IMyInterface x = new MyClass();
x.B();
```

Comment: No, there is nothing you can do. That's not how default implementations work. They don't add anything to the class. You can inherit from a base **class** that provides that method, but the interface doesn't make that method available through a class reference.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's really unfortunate. This is how default implementations work in other languages like Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it like:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
(x as IMyInterface).B();
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a bit of a hack, but you could use a class extension to add the B() method to every class that implements IMyInterface.

```
static class ImplIMyInterface
{
    public static void B(this IMyInterface obj) => obj.B();
}
```

Now you can call B() on an instance of MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do that. you must implement the interface that your class has inherited from it. but you can use abstract class instead of interface. like this:

```
 abstract class MyAbstract
{
    public void A() { }

   public void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

class MyClass : MyAbstract
{
    public new void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

var x = new MyClass();
    x.B();
```